# perl bash script don't insert sql query

Tags: bash, shell, perl

i want to insert a query but not work :

```
my $query1 = $db1->prepare("SELECT host, name, severity  FROM XX");  
my $query2 = $db2->prepare('UPDATE worldmap_table' . ' SET severity = ?, name = ? WHERE HOST = ?');

$query1->execute;

while (my @row = $query1->fetchrow_array) {
    $query2->execute($row[2]);
    print "$row[2]\n";
}
```

preparation query 3

```
my $query3 = $db1->prepare("SELECT host, name, severity
  FROM XX);
```

preparation query 4

```
my $query4 = $db2->prepare('UPDATE worldmap_table' . ' SET severity = 6, name = ? WHERE HOST = ?');

$query3->execute;
```

this part not work

```
while (my @row2 = $query3->fetchrow_array) {
    $query4->execute($row2[2], $row2[1], $row2[0]);
    print "$row2[2], $row2[1], $row2[0] \n";
}
```

i have this error:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 3 bind variables when 2 are needed at worldmap2.pl line 103.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 3 bind variables when 2 are needed at worldmap2.pl line 103.
```

Comment: You seem to have left out important bits of your code like where you call `execute` on the prepared statement (And what you did include has errors and appears to be missing bits)... but the error message should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

There are two placeholders in query 4:

```
my $query4 = $db2->prepare(
    'UPDATE worldmap_table' . ' SET severity = 6, name = ? WHERE HOST = ?'
    #                                                    ~              ~
);
```

But you're calling it with only one argument:

```
$query4->execute($row2[2]);
#                ~~~~~~~~
```

The error message mentions different numbers, so I guess you simplified the code.

Comment: i changed the query 4